# How can I search for "http" in every file in firefox's cache folder?

Tags: python, sqlite, firefox, caching

I am working on extracting all useful information from Firefox's cache in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\orlxb2co.default-release\cache2\entries.

How can I use python to access every file in the directory above and search for the URL link in the files?

This is what I have so far:

```
firefox_profile_path = os.path.join(paths.homePath(), 'AppData', 'Local', 'Mozilla', 'Firefox', 'Profiles','cache2')
for cache_name in glob.glob(firefox_profile_path):
    with open(cache_name, 'rb') as file_cache:
        data = file_cache.read()
        firefox_db |= set(re.findall("(http.*?)\x00", data))
        print(firefox_db)
```

Comment: do you get error message or what ?

Comment: you should add `/*` to your path so `glob` will search all files in folder `cache2`. Wit current path `glob` searchs only folder but not files inside folder. BTW: and you forgot `entries` in your path.

Comment: @furas Hi, i added /*. The error messages are  
    firefox_db |= set(re.findall("(http.*?)\x00", data))
and in find all return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: you will have to use prefix `b` in `b"(http.*?)\x00"` to have bytes-like object.